# android2.3 DownloadManager

Tags: android, download, android-download-manager

I use `DownloadManager`, which in available since Android 2.3, to download FTP. But it does not work.

I do not know how to make it work? I did not find proper examples. Does `DownloadManager` support FTP?

Comment: No, it doesn't. It supports only `HTTP` downloads. You can find more information about `DownloadManager` from documentation: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunatelly, FTP won't work.

`DownloadManager` supports HTTP. And HTTPS is supported since ICS.
If you try downloading from FTP you receive one of these exceptions:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can only download HTTP URIs

or

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can only download HTTP/HTTPS URIs